# What is the difference between pcie root complex and host bus adapter

Tags: pci-express, hostadapter

In this Wikipedia link [PCI Express](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express) I found a diagram of pcie where the cpu is connected to the pcie bus and devices through the root complex and then I saw this link [Host adapter](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_adapter) which says that the host bus adapter connects the system bus (which is the bus the cpu uses to communicate with ram , I guess) to a storage and network devices which may be using the pcie bus .

Question : Is the host bus adapter considered to be the pcie root complex in that case

Comment: You probably don’t have a HBA installed in your system unless you have a HBA card installed in your system. Do you have a HBA card? If you do you [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

> Question : Is the host bus adapter considered to be the pcie root complex in that case

No, because that is not even the case. Devices called "HBA" are usually meant to attach a more specialized bus *to* the existing PCI system bus.

For example, a very common type of HBA would be a PCI device that connects a SCSI bus to the host (as in the Wikipedia page).

The PCIe root complex itself is not usually called a HBA as the PCI bus is usually considered part of the host already.